# Can we live only on chocolate?

Tags: nutrition, diet, side-effects, food-safety

This question is out of curiosity. I have a new colleague. I haven't seen him going out for lunch or eating anything else but chocolate. He eats only chocolate bars whole day, about 3 big bars every day.

I didn't ask him why, since it seems personal. But I am curious about how eating only chocolate affects our nutrition system, regarding to protein and stuff.

Comment: how exactly do you know what he is eating at other times of the day, and weekends?  This could just be a sampling error.

Comment: @GrahamChiu You could just accept the answer as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 oz (28g) of dark has 155 calories. If you scale these 155 calories to 2000 (13 oz) then it looks like this:

[image]

> <sup>*Source*: United States Department of Agriculture, National Nutrient Database for Standard Reference Release 28, **[Basic Report:  19902, Chocolate, dark, 45- 59% cacao solids](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/6451?man=&lfacet=&count=&max=50&qlookup=19902&offset=&sort=default&format=Abridged&reportfmt=other&rptfrm=&ndbno=&nutrient1=&nutrient2=&nutrient3=&subset=&totCount=&measureby=&Qv=1&Q12135=13&Q12136=1&Qv=1&Q12135=1&Q12136=1)**</sup>

Below is a table with the daily value:

```
% Daily Value*      
Total Fat 9 g          13.00%   167.74%
Saturated fat 5 g      25.00%   322.58% 
Cholesterol 2 mg        0.00%     0.00%
Sodium 7 mg             0.00%     0.00%
Potassium 158 mg        4.00%    51.61%
Total Carbohydrate 17 g 5.00%    64.52%
Dietary fiber 2 g       8.00%   103.23%
Sugar 14 g      
Protein 1.4 g           2.00%    25.81%
```

Naturally it is high on fat. About the only guidelines chocolate meets are cholesterol and fiber.

Chocolate is also low on essential vitamins.

Clearly over the long term it will negatively impact health.

3 each 10 oz bars is even more.  It is 4,650 calories.

Comment: interesting, I would not have expected it to provide enough fibre. For reference are these numbers for milk or dark chocolate, and what quantity of chocolate provides the amounts in the last column?

Comment: I just took the first hit on google to chocolate - dark.  It is 2000 / 15 = 13.

Comment: @LangLangC OP did not state type of chocolate nor bar size.  I posted what I consider a very responsible answer based on the information.   You can slice this any way you want and fat is going to be high, protein low, and carb and fiber surprising close.  From a basic nutrition perspective it is going to be a problem before the vitamin deficiency kicks in.  Glad I am relatively sound.

Comment: @LangLangC I edited.

Comment: What cholesterol guideline?  We do require references.

Comment: @GrahamChiu Not going to interact with you.  I have asked you the same question before and got no response.  Your answer is zero so you will just say it is wrong.  I get you have high rep here and feel like you are a bit of a bully.

Comment: @LangLangC No link.  It comes up on the right in Google.  I think it is a good responsible answer and sorry you don't feel the same.

Comment: answers without references are not acceptable.

Comment: @GrahamChiu and paparazzo: Why is the tone in the comments so hostile? I think we‘re all on the same page that quality should improve on Health.SE. I think it’s important to note that anyone here is trying to bully someone else, it’s just that there a guidelines and on meta there happen to be quite a few discussion about improving quality, and our dissatisfaction with the way of the site. // I think this answer is sound and with a link to any daily recommendation and the ingredients of a random chocolate piece, the question would also meet the guidelines for references.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma The table is percentages of daily recommendation.   It is the required guidelines for a food label in the US.  The answer has a reference.

Comment: @paparazzo Looking at your link, I can find **absolute** values, but not percentage of daily value. In order for you to make the claim about daily values, I'm afraid you will have to include *a link* to the official DV guideline. As I said before, **with a link to any daily recommendation which validates your claims below** (that are currently unsubstantiated) this will be an excellent answer.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma When I google that is what comes up as the top hit on the right.  There not url - for the search.  That is the reference URL to the table that has the %.

Comment: See, it doesn't show up in my google search. (Google gives different results based on location and language, obviously). That's what I'm having the problem with. You need a reference in your answer, and *just google it* isn't a reference. Google probably got that number from somewhere...

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma I know Google can do that.  I did not think I was going down a dead end.  I will see if I can find a link with that answer?  Otherwise I will just delete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74680/discussion-between-narusan-in-coma-and-paparazzo).